# COUNTIF with 2 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table in Excel

[image]

The function that you see is translated in `COUNTIF`. As you can see the **FORMULA** is repeated for all the rows

What I would like to ask:

- Is there a way to write the **FORMULA** based also on the criteria **G3 = GES**? So in **F2** I will get the result of **150** only if in the cell **G3** there is the value **GES**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show the full 150 if the cell value in column D is GES? Please check the code below. Tested, screenshot attached.

```
=IF(C2=$G$3;SUMIF($E$2:$E$6;$G$2;$D$2:$D$6);0)
```

/edit, missed some $-signs.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you.